# c#:How to make typed dataset or some another structure at runtime?

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, openxml-sdk, strongly-typed-dataset

Good day! 
I try to make typed dataset or datatable at runtime without DB.

I have Excel file, and want to parse it and make typed dataset.
Because, if so- i can do something like that:

```
foreach(Person personRow in dataSetPerson.Rows)
{
  var name=personRow.name;//etc
}
```

But i can not. I try to do it from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836025/how-do-i-create-strongly-typed-dataset-during-runtime-using-c), but failed.

Please, tell me how to make some typed structure(dataset or may be another one) at runtime?Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jet oledb.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\MyExcel.xls;
Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";

And then write a query for your excell file.

```
string query = "SELECT [aa],[bb],[cc] FROM [Sheet1$]";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionStringsRef);
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

            var XXX = ds.Tables[0];

da.Dispose();
conn.Close();
conn.Dispose();
```